# Como fazer a variavel aparecer na tela antes dela ser modificada?

Tags: variáveis, visualg

Estou começando agora a estudar programação e por conta disso estou usando o VisualG para ser mais fácil de pegar a lógica de programação. Acontece que eu estou tentando desenvolver um algoritmo que adivinhe a idade da pessoa. É bem simples, porém eu não estou conseguindo fazer alguns detalhes nesse algoritmo.

```
algoritmo "valores"
var
N1,S,S2: inteiro
inicio
Escreva ("Olá, vou adivinhar a sua idade. Pense em um numero de 1 a 10: ")
Leia (N1)
S <- N1 * 2
Escreva ("OK, multipliquei esse numero por 2 e a soma é ",S,". Agora vou adicionar 5")
S <- N1 + 5
Escreva ("A soma entre"
fimalgoritmo
```

Esta incompleto como podem ver. Eu queria colocar na última linha de código o número da variável `S` antes dela ser modificada pelo `+ 5`. Não sei explicar direito, mas vou dar um exemplo:

Vamos supor que a pessoa escolha o numero 5. O programa vai fazer x2 que vai dar 10 e logo em seguida eu queria que na ultima linha de código aparecesse esse 10 na variável "N" e depois no final do comando escreva aparecesse o "15". Apareceria algo como "A soma entre 10 e 5, é 15".

Como eu faço isso?

Obrigado a todos que me responderem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Arthur, você tem 3 variáveis definidas `S`,`S2` e `N1`, certo? Então vamos utilizar as `S` e `S2`.

Conforme fez, e esta correto, guardar o valor em `S` da multiplicação:
`S <- N1 * 2`

Agora vamos utilizar o valor que está em `S` para realizar a soma de `+5`:
`S2 <- S + 2`

E então exibir para o usuário a mensagem:
`Escreva ("A soma entre ",S," e 5, é ",S2)`

O código completo ficando:

```
algoritmo "valores"
var
N1,S,S2: inteiro
inicio
Escreva ("Olá, vou adivinhar a sua idade. Pense em um numero de 1 a 10: ")
Leia (N1)
S <- N1 * 2
Escreval ("OK, multipliquei esse numero por 2 e a soma é ",S,". Agora vou adicionar 5")
S2 <- S + 5
Escreva ("A soma entre ",S," e 5, é ",S2)
fimalgoritmo
```

Comment: Muito obrigado pela explicação

Comment: Conseguiu resolver problema, se sim marca como resolvida a resposta que mais te ajudou :)

Comment: Como eu marco a melhor resposta?Comecei recentemente nesse forum

Comment: Na pergunta desejada a marcar como melhor resposta, do lado esquerdo tem um simbolo de Certo, clique nele. Caso não consiga acesse o [tour] para maiores detalhes.

Comment: Pronto.Caso não tenha adiantado é só avisar

Comment: Deu certo sim, obrigado Arthur

Answer (score 1):

Eu nunca usei o visualg, então tu tem que modificar do jeito ai :)

Se eu entendi, você pode atribuir esses valores em variaveis diferentes ou pedir para imprimir o valor antes de você somar!

Seria algo do tipo:

```
valor pensando: n1
multiplica: m (n1*2)
soma: s (m+5)
```

Na hora de exibir: "O valor pensado é 'n1', multiplicado é 'm' e o total é 's'..

ou

```
valor pensando: n1
multiplica: s (n1*2)
```

mostra na tela a variável s, antes de ser modificada, agora você modifica:

```
soma: s (m+5)
```

imprimi agora na tela a variável modificada :)

Espero que eu tenho entendido bem e que minha explicação tenha ficado boa, rs...

enfim, espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Muito obrigado!Vou tentar fazer isso